# R: trouble assigning values to a dynamic variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign values to a dataframe variable defined by the user.  The user specifies the name of the variable, let's call this x, in the dataframe df. For simplicity I want to assign a value of 3 to everything in the column the user specifies. The simplified code is:

```
variableName <- paste("df$", x, sep="")
eval(parse(text=variableName)) <- 3
```

But I get an error:

> Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(filename, "r") :
>     cannot open file 'df$x': No such file or directory

I've tried all kinds of remedies to no avail.  If I simply try to print the values of the column.

```
eval(parse(text=variableName))
```

I get no errors and it prints out ok.  It's only when I try to give that column a value that I get the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `df[["x"]] <- 3`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think maybe lose the quotes around `x`, I think the OP is looking for the value stored in x not x itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that there is no way to use the result of `eval()` on the LHS of an assignment.

```
df = data.frame(foo = 1:5,
                bar = -3)
x = "bar"
variableName <- paste("df$", x, sep="")
eval(parse(text=variableName)) <- 3
#> Warning in file(filename, "r"): cannot open file 'df$bar': No such file or
#> directory
#> Error in file(filename, "r"): cannot open the connection

## This error is a bit misleading. Breaking it apart I get a different error.

eval(expression(df$bar)) <- 3
#> Error in eval(expression(df$bar)) <- 3: could not find function "eval<-"


## And it works if you put it all in the string to be parsed. 

ex1 <- paste0("df$", x, "<-3")
eval(parse(text=ex1))

df
#>   foo bar
#> 1   1   3
#> 2   2   3
#> 3   3   3
#> 4   4   3
#> 5   5   3

## But I doubt that's the best way to do it!
```